# Border radius not fitting properly on the image (React Native)

Tags: react-native, image

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Dimensions, Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

const GameOverScreen = () => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
          <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: 'https://www.photocircle.net/public/uploads/photos/thumbnail_1000x1000/99732-You-Got-This-rose--by-photocircle-.jpg'}} 
              style={styles.image} 
            />
          </View>
      </View>
  )
}

export default GameOverScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width > 400 ? 150 : 100,
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginVertical: 15,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width > 400 ? 300 : 200,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height > 700 ? 300 : 200,
    borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width > 400 ? 150 : 100,
  }
})
```

The above code currently renders the following output (for larger screen sizes like iPhone 11)
[image]

The following is for smaller devices like iPhone 8
[image: image with border radius on smaller screen sizes]

As can be seen here, there is extra white spaces along the right and left sides of the image, which is not desirable. Also, the border up and down the image looks like a flat line rather than circle. How to properly fixed this so that the border sticks to the circular image?

This is my desired output:
[image: desired output]

Answer (score 0):

Give height and width by comparing same value instead compare and give height and width according to window height and width.
For example, try below styling

```
  imageContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width > 400 ? 300 : 200,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width > 400 ? 300 : 200,
    borderRadius: 300, // Border radius can be any value higher than half of the height/width to get circle shape, so no need to compare
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginVertical: 15,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width > 400 ? 300 : 200,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width > 400 ? 300 : 200, // compare with same value as width results height and width same to get circle shape
    borderRadius: 300 // like mentioned above
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working to give the desired output.

Comment: Try updated code with same height and width for both container and image

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dimensions, Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

const GameOverScreen = () => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
          <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: 'https://www.photocircle.net/public/uploads/photos/thumbnail_1000x1000/99732-You-Got-This-rose--by-photocircle-.jpg'}} 
              style={styles.image} 
            />
          </View>
      </View>
  )
}

export default GameOverScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width/2,
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginVertical: 15,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width/2,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width/2,
    borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width/2,
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working to give the desired output. And I do not want circle to be always half the width of the screen. And even if it is the case, the border doesn't adjust to fit the circle anyways.